# SQL SERVER 2008 - SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am new to SSAS and would like your help on the following scenario.

I am in process of designing Store Dimension hierarchies. Scenario is that

Hierarchy 1: Retailer (Ret Id Key) --> Store Name (Store Id key)

Hierarchy 2: Store Name (Store Id key) --> Region Name (Reg Id) --> Customer (Cus Id)

Since Store Id is the primary key on the dimension table, the Hierarchy 1 has no issues, but whilst designing Hierarchy 2, I have the blue squiggly line that appears. I tried to define attribute relationships and for Hierarchy 1 the relation ship

Store ID --> Ret Id

But for Hierarchy 2

I defined the relationship as

Store ID --> Reg Id --> Cus Id

But Since Store ID is the first (Top) level in Hierarchy 2 and leaf level in Hierarchy 1, for Hierarchy 2 the blue squiggly line does not disappear even though the relationship is defined.

Is there something I am missing in this scenario or Does this scenario cannot be handled.

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Should StoreID not be the bottom level if it is the finest detail? I a hierarchy the coarsest level is the top level.

Comment: Depending on how your associations are set up, the squiggly blue line is more of a "you're not doing this according to best practice" vs. "this won't work". However, as the above person noted, the hierarchy order you suggest does seem off - you're going to want Store ID (assuming it's the dimension key) at the bottom of the hierarchy.